# Parse Facebook login check for first login

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I'm using a `PFLoginViewController` in my app to log in using Facebook.

Because it uses Facebook there is no real difference to the user between signing up (i.e. logging in for the first time) and logging in (i.e. subsequent log ins, after a log out for example).

I'd like to change the flow for the user if it's there first log in. For instance, take them to a screen to "fill out" their account etc...

Is there any way to check if this is a first login using the `PFLoginViewController` and its delegate methods? Or do I have to do it my own way (i.e. storing a flag on the `PFUser` object to say they have completed their account).

Hmm... I might just do that anyway. I could inspect the "number of logins" or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call: `if (user.isNew)`

From the api doc:

Whether the PFUser was just created from a request. This is only set after a Facebook or Twitter login.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a special way for that, but why not just check the `createdAt` property of the `currentUser()`? If it has just been created, then this is first login.